# How does docker cache the layer?

Tags: docker, containers

I have a docker image which run the following command

```
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential debhelper rpm ruby ruby-dev sudo cmake make gcc g++ flex bison git libpcap-dev libssl-dev ninja-build openssh-client python-dev python3-pip swig zlib1g-dev python3-setuptools python3-requests wget curl unzip zip default-jdk && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

If I run it couple time in the same day, the layer seems cached. However, docker will think the layer changed if I run it for the first time daily.

Just wonder what's special in the above command that makes docker thinks the layer changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not caused by docker. When docker sees a RUN command, all it does is simple string comparison to determine whether the layer is in the cache or not. If it sees it in cache, it will reuse it and if not, it will run it.

Since you have mentioned that it builds whole day using cache and then it doesn't the next day, the only possible explanation is that the cache has been invalidated/deleted during that time by someone/something.

I don't know how/where you are running the docker daemon but it may be the case that it is running in VM that is being recreated each day from a base image which would then destroy all the cache and force docker to rebuild the image.

Another explanation is that you have some cleanup process running once a day, maybe some cron that deletes the cache.

Bottom line is that docker will happily reuse that cache for unlimited period of time, as long as the cache actually exists.

*I am assuming that previous layers has been built from cache (if there are any), otherwise you should look for `COPY/ADD` commands if they are not causing the cache busting due to file changes in your build context.*

Answer (score 1):

It's not the command, it's the steps that occur before it. Specifically, if the files being copied to previous layers were modified. I can be more specific if you'll edit the post to show all the steps in the Dockerfile before this one.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache):

> Aside from the ADD and COPY commands, cache checking does not look at the files in the container to determine a cache match. For example, when processing a RUN apt-get -y update command the files updated in the container are not examined to determine if a cache hit exists. In that case just the command string itself is used to find a match

For a `RUN` command， it just command string itself is used to find a match. So, maybe any processes delete the cache layer， or maybe you changed your Dockerfile?